# vbs run program with objShell.run

Tags: vbscript

I have the following vbscript that fail with an error on last line

```js
Option Explicit
Dim  objShell
Dim strComputer, strCmd , strVar
strComputer = "."
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
' strVar = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles(x86)%")
' strCmd = strVar & "\CaptureBites\Express\Programs\AutoBites\Autobites.exe"
' wscript.echo strCmd
objShell.Run "taskkill /im Autobites.exe",,True
WScript.Sleep(5000)
objShell.run """%ProgramFiles(x86)%""" &"\CaptureBites\Express\Programs\AutoBites\Autobites.exe"
```

The problem is that script open the folder `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` but don't run the exe `autobites.exe`
Can you help me to debug it

Answer (score 1):

The whole file spec has to be quoted, not only the first part:

```
objShell.run """%ProgramFiles(x86)%" &"\CaptureBites\Express\Programs\AutoBites\Autobites.exe"""
```